# How to get ID only using findBySlug method

Tags: cakephp

Trying to get ID by findBySlug method in CakePHP, for example

```
$this->Page->findBySlug(1);
```

this will return all fields, but i need only ID to be returned , i have searched lot but could not find function reference as well and try following but get an Error

```
$this->Page->findBySlug(15, array('fields'=>array('Page.id')));
```

any solution within the function that doesn't use a custom query?

Comment: which version of cakephp are you using?

Comment: `but get an Error` - the error should be in the question; note that [the docs say how to do that](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#findby). `findBy<fieldName>(string $value[, mixed $fields` <-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cakephp2

```
$page = $this->Page->findBySlug(1, array('id'));

$id = $page['Page']['id'];
```

cakephp3

```
$page = $this->Pages->findBySlug(1)
    ->select('id');

$id = $page->id;
```